# Embed react native app inside existing android app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to create a page made with `native android` with a small portion (say a horizontal scroll view) made from `react-native` inside the same `android` page like an `android` page with a `react-native` widget plugged in, such that the app is completely widgetized.

I know that it is possible to do so because I read about it in [this article](https://lambda.grofers.com/starting-with-react-native-at-grofers-a-guide-to-using-react-native-components-inside-native-bbdd6a3470d4) and some companies are using it.
Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

My question is same to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327263/embed-react-native-app-inside-existing-ios-android-app), I found a few useful articles related to this matter for `iOS` but I want a solution for `android`.